# Azure AD groups (security and M365 both) not showing up in Azure Devops Environment approvers option

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I created some security and microsoft 365 groups from the Azure portal. These are showing up when adding them to an Azure Devops team:

[image]

However, when adding them as an approver in an environment, these groups don't show up:

[image]

I am not sure what the issue causing this is. I have checked, other AAD groups created before the group I am looking for are showing up. The group I am looking for was created more than a week ago so it is not a sync delay issue either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested in my environment.

I have two groups named Test Group and Devops Group in my Azure AD

Under Teams, I added the Devops Group

Now when adding the approvers in the environment, I can see only Devops Group. I cannot see the Test Group.

So, if you want to add the Azure AD Group as approver in the environment, first you need to add the group under Teams